# admob interstitial iOS testing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

i want to be able to request interstitial test ads on iOS on the simulator
this is the code I'm using

```
interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
interstitial_.adUnitID = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
[interstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
interstitial_.delegate = self;
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your specific question. But, the [Google Mobile Ads SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#ios) is very rich. Here's the code which I often use -

```
- (void)loadAdMobIntersBanner
{
    interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    interstitial_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx";
    interstitial_.delegate = self;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [interstitial_ loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad
{
    [interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, does this request (test) ads ?

Comment: @user3685876 Of course, you can see the ads since you will be using your unique adUnitID. 'Test' may not be the best word here, but the answer to your question is *yes*. Go ahead and try yourself - if that's what you meant.